# Unable to install Laravel 4 in linux using composer

Tags: installation, laravel, laravel-4

i am not able to install L4 on linux(ubuntu) with (PHP 5.4.9-4ubuntu2.2)  using composer, below is the error screen shot, i update composer, even installed new composer still getting  same error, it's working fine in windows

[image: Composer Error]

### Solved

> Thanks you all for your inputs and sorry for bothering, the problem is with our firewall it was
>   blocking swiftmailer/swiftmailer package url on linux box which was
>   causing this issue, and confusion is due to composer's wrong message, I think its verifying signature but not URL or domain
>   when i used curl to open the url then i found that our firewall is blocking the URL and redirecting to an internal error url see below screen shot

[image: Curl]

Answer (score 2):

Try installing it with `--prefer-source` or `--prefer-dist`

`php composer.phar create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist`

or

`php composer.phar create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-source`

Comment: i was using 
 composer create-project laravel/laravel your-project-name --prefer-dist
same problem
tried 
--prefer-source also no use

Comment: @ArunKumar check https://status.github.com/ when you suffer from a similar issue. Either GitHub is down/nonfunctional or your connection has problems.

Comment: @Arda it was working in windows with the same connection, i was able to  clone from github also but having problem in composer

Comment: @ArunKumar is openSSL installed? Then it's most possibly because of that.

Comment: @Arda Yes openSSL is installed in my linux box, i found that only swiftmailer/swiftmailer is giving error, i tried to install only swiftmailer package then also i am getting same security exception, where i am able to install other packages using composer

Comment: thanks all for your input, the problem is with our firewall it was blocking swiftmailer/swiftmailer package url on linux box which was causing this issue,

Answer (score 0):

First install composer globally using terminal,

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Then install latest laravel from downloaded version.
First download and extract latest framework from [Github](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/archive/master.zip)

Then in terminal change your directory to project root folder, like

```
cd /var/www/laravel-master/
```

Or

```
cd /opt/lampp/htdocs/laravel-master
```

Then run composer installation,

```
composer install
```

If you are getting some timeout error use,

```
COMPOSER_PROCESS_TIMEOUT=24000 composer install
```

Or

```
COMPOSER_PROCESS_TIMEOUT=24000 composer update
```

Answer (score 0):

Something to try would be to delete the composer cache located at `~/.composer/cache/`.  This will force composer to download all packages again instead of using what you have in cache. If there was an error when getting Swiftmailer the first time, it will continually try to pull that bad copy.

Also, try deleting your vendor directory in your project and running `composer install` again.